# Logging Windows Syscalls in the kernel Level

Tags: windows, logging, kernel, system-calls, gdi

## Windows Syscall logging from the kernel

Hi. I'm trying to log specific system calls (win32k) that are called in Windows 7. I've tried a couple of ways already. The first thing i tried was [drstrace](http://drmemory.org/strace_for_windows.html). It's the exact kind of output that I need ( Function Name, Paramters, and return value ), but not all the system calls are getting logged. I'm not 100% sure why this happens but system calls like NtGdiSet~ types are called at once using NtGdiFlush, so these system calls cannot be captured at the user level.

Next I tried logman and xperf, and these seem log those functions drstrace couldn't but they do not resolve system call names (this is not such a big deal actually), and they don't log parameters. And also it does log the return value of the system call but it does not match from which call the return value came from and this is kind of a big deal.

I've thought of building a driver to hook functions at the kernel level, but I've never developed a driver and it didn't work out very well..

So I want to ask if there already is program that can do this or how can i build a driver that can log what I want?

Comment: So, what is a **question**?

Comment: Sorry. I've added what I really want to ask

Comment: Why? What's the problem you're really trying to solve?

Comment: drstrace cannot trace all the system calls I need and logman does not trace the parameters and does not match return values to its called function. I need something that is a combination of both

Comment: Why? 1234567890